# How can I Use this Implicitly-typed Arrays class

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a class like this and I cannot change and only have to use it. this class defines an Implicitly-typed array such a list that in each row we have an index and a data(as producer says):

```
public partial class LightPenMeta {

    private long lightPenIDField;

    private byte[] lightPenDataField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public long LightPenID {
        get {
            return this.lightPenIDField;
        }
        set {
            this.lightPenIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="base64Binary")]
    public byte[] LightPenData {
        get {
            return this.lightPenDataField;
        }
        set {
            this.lightPenDataField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is I have to use it and define an array type of LightPenMeta[] which contains for example LightPenID=0 ,LightPenData= '' in row 0.

this code returns null exception:

```
var lp = new LightPenMeta[1];

        lp[0].LightPenData = Data;
        lp[0].LightPenID = 0;
```

the question is how can I use this class and fill it's row?

Comment: Initialize the member first, like lp[0] = new LightPenMeta()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the first element within your array

```
LightPenMeta[] lp = new LightPenMeta[1]; //instantiate your array 
lp[0] = new LightPenMeta(); //initialize the first element here
lp[0].LightPenData = Data;
lp[0].LightPenID = 0;
```

---

In one line

```
LightPenMeta[] lp = new LightPenMeta[1];
lp[0] = new LightPenMeta() { LightPenData = Data, LightPenID = 0 };
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you.